# Reading StandardInput stops code execution without breaking application

Tags: c#, multithreading

Im using [Stockfish](http://stockfishchess.org/) game engine to power Human Vs Computer games.
Here is first part of the code:

```
Process _proc= new Process();
_proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
_proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
_proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
_proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
_proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
_proc.Start();
_proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("uci");
_proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("ucinewgame");
```

At this point everything is ok, but when I try to read StandardOutput something weird happens.

```
string result = _proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Stockfish.exe program pops-up my application is running but code after that line is not executing. When I press pause, it points at this line:

> [image]

If I use:

```
while (!_proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    result += _proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
}
```

Same thing happens only at while statement. result has its full value there, all the text is written into it.

**Is there any way to overcome this without async reading?**

Side problem:

Since this is all part of singleton class that is used over whole ASP.NET application, i dont feel like using async reading since Im not sure how can I protect (with locking) multiple threads writing into it. Also, I dont know how to stop current thread since the processing of command can last up to 10 sec.

*I don't feel like using Thread.Sleep() to constantly check for end of reading output, not elegant.*

**Considering side problem, how could i avoid multithread problems if async is only solution?**

My threading knowledge is weak, so please have that in mind when giving thread related answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The call to [StandardOutput.ReadToEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) will block until this process ends.  Is the goal here to read, process, and respond to various text commands from the process you spawn as you receive them?
You must approach this via asynchronous reading.

For example, you could setup a listener to [Process.OutputDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx).  Then call [Process.BeginOutputReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx) to start reading.  Your code will continue execution.  Meanwhile, the .NET Framework will handle incoming text messages on a separate thread.

Comment: The problem is that when I use ReadLine() it works as long as there are lines. If I use it when there is no more text that engine returned, it breaks like in the picture. Worst thing is, I do not know how many lines there is, and there is no way to get length or detect end of data.
I used the async aproach, it works good, the program doesnt enter the "dead lock", but it creates other problems such as: my program continues but engine did not return all the data.